# Vue - directive bind doesn't work on element refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, directive, input-mask

I use vue.js to generate forms - all fields are in javascript objects array in structure like:

```
{
    type: "input",
    mask: "date",
    default: "2018/04/14"
},
{
    type: "input",
    mask: "currency",
    default: "0"
}
```

User can jump to any question using navigation. When user clicks navigation link, I changed my "currentQuestion" object to selected by user - object are pass by reference in JS, so if user modify something, I have results in my "central" array. And it's ok.

I also use inputmask for masking inputs fields with very simple directive:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Inputmask from 'inputmask'

Vue.directive('mask', {
  bind (el, binding) {
    if (binding.value) {
      Inputmask(binding.value).mask(el)
    }
  }
})
```

And it's also works fine... but not always. If user have a question with date mask, then jump to question with other mask and come back - date will not work. User must go to question without mask, then go back and it will work again.

After debugging, I know, that element is refreshed, but vue not bind correct data (from currentQuestion) to input:

```
methods: {
  getInputMask () {
    return this.currentQuestion.mask || null
  },
```

and usage:

```
<input type="text"
    :name="currentQuestion.identifier"
    v-mask="getInputMask()"
    v-model="currentQuestion.value"
    @keyup="afterModifyInput"
>
```

In result, I don't know how can fix this issue

Comment: This sounds like you might [need a key](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) on your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an **id** for each element and use **v-bind:key** something like this:

```
<input type="text"
    v-bind:key="YOUR_ELEMENT.id"
    v-mask="getInputMask()"
    v-model="currentQuestion.value"
    @keyup="afterModifyInput"
>
```

I suppose this is your id

```
:name="currentQuestion.identifier"
```

Well, **v-bind** is used when you don’t know the exact content you’re going to render like a properties from request or JSON file.